# Microsoft SQL Server - Connection String

Tags: c#, sql-server

I can't connect to server because I don't know how to write my User ID which contains COMPUTER\Кирилл. It has an error message because of 'Error    CS1009  Unrecognized escape sequence'

```
var connectionString = $"Data Source={dbHost};Initial Catalog={dbName};User ID='COMPUTER\Кирилл';Password={dbPassword}";
```

Comment: Use [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class.

Comment: Use SQL Server Management to connect to server.  The connection string should match the login window of SSMS.  A server has two different types of logins 1) Window Credential and connection string should have Integrated security = true 2) SQL Credentials user name password.  The Data Source in connection string should also be the same instance of server in the SSMS login window.

Answer (score 0):

var connectionString = @"Data Source={dbHost};Initial Catalog={dbName};User ID='COMPUTER\Кирилл';Password={dbPassword}";

Comment: SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).